# Javascript returning different value depending on profile setting

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am getting different values in javascript on vfPage. When Manage Custom Permissions and Customized application checkbox is true, javascript returns value as per calculation and when that checkbox is not true javascript returns null.
[image: When checkbox is false[![When Checkbox is true]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jvu1.png)

Comment: Please share the object, fields which you are referring/

Comment: The checkbox i have mentioned above is in profile setting of salesuser and i am using javascript to retrieve number of rows and data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been solved by changing object deployment status from in development to deployed and i have also removed Manage Custom Permissions and Customized application, view setup and configuration permissions from profile.